# Why isn't NetBeans waiting for user input?

Tags: java, netbeans

So I'm having a problem with my code when ran (I just started yesterday, so please help). NetBeans doesn't wait for user input, thus it just says something weird in the output, next to my text.

```
package javalol;

/**
*
* @author sandy_000
*/
public class JavaLol {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Printf="Please enter your first name:";
    String Printl="Please enter your last name:";
    System.out.println(Printf);
    String firstName=System.in.toString();
    System.out.println(Printl);
    String lastName=System.in.toString();
    Friend friend=new Friend(firstName, lastName);
    System.out.println("How are ya, "+friend+"?!");
 }

}
```

Output:

```
Please enter your first name:
Please enter your last name:
How are ya, Friend{firstName=java.io.BufferedInputStream@15db9742, lastName=java.io.BufferedInputStream@15db9742}?!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: You don't want to call `System.in.toString()` (that calls `PrintStream.toString()`) You need a `Scanner` or `Reader` and to wrap `System.in` to read.

Answer (score 1):

`System.in` doesn't read your input, because it is a variable for the standard input. This is why the output is `java.io.BufferedInputStream@15db9742`.

You have to use a `Scanner` to read the input (remember to import `java.util.Scanner` for that).

Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Printf="Please enter your first name:";
    String Printl="Please enter your last name:";
    System.out.println(Printf);
    String firstName=scan.next();
    System.out.println(Printl);
    String lastName=scan.next();
    Friend friend=new Friend(firstName, lastName);
    System.out.println("How are ya, "+friend+"?!");
    scan.close();
 }
```

For good code style it is better to write `printf` and `printl` instead of `Printf` and `Printl`.

When you haven't overwritten the `toString()` method for the `Friend` class you will get another problem in your output. So it is better to use `getter` methods for the variables and change your output to this: `System.out.println("How are ya, " + friend.getFirstName + friend.getLastName() + "?!");`

Comment: I tried using Scanner in my first code (project) and it brought back an error (I think that I'm suppose to make another class for Scanner, but I don't know how to do that nor do I have the nerves). Also, in that project I then tried using `System.in.read()` and it worked there. Is the `toString()` the core of my problem? Also, if that's the case, how do I make the class (I don't mean: "How do I add a file to my project?", I mean: "How do I know what code to put into the class to make it work how it should be?")? P.S. I'm a beginner, so go easy with the code (explain the `.next()` function).

Comment: To understand the `.next()` function you should learn to read [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). `System.in.read()` does not do what you expect (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()))